# How can i import millions of records from client database into mine in less time

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.STSQ01
WHERE BegSchSessYr BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE())-3 AND YEAR(GETDATE())-1
```

This is my query to pull the 3 last years of data from clients database and the records are millions and it is taking a lot of times to fetch the data. how can i make my query run more quick.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server? You tagged the question [tag:mysql], but `dbo` and `GETDATE()` suggests you are using Microsoft. These are two different products, and the best answer might depend on which you are really using. Also tagging questions accurately is important because other Stack Overflow users follow the tags for the technology they are best at answering, so using the right tags will attract attention from the people best able to give you the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need an index on BegSchSessYr column if you don't have already:

```
create index on STSQ01 (BegSchSessYr)
```

also only select columns that you want

Answer (score 0):

Write a script in whatever programming language that runs it in chunks using LIMIT clause. So you only grab like 50,000 records at a time. Should speed things up.